# Animating sub controls of UIView

Tags: ios, animation

I am trying to animate uiview. That is, on button click view will appear through animation. This works properly. But when I try to remove that view through animation, animation is applied on the view and not on its sub controls. That is, view gets disappeared but all its sub controls are viewable.

So my question is how can I remove uiview along with its subcontrol using animation. My current code is:

To animate uiview code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5f animations:^{
        CGRect theFrame = self.viewFilter.frame;
        theFrame.size.height += 140.f;
        self.viewFilter.frame = theFrame;
    }];
```

To hide uiview:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5f animations:^{
    CGRect theFrame = self.viewFilter.frame;
    theFrame.size.height -= 140.0f;
    self.viewFilter.frame = theFrame;
}];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: there is property clip subview just tick that from interface builder

Comment: Are the subcontrols properly placed inside the View that you're animating? I use same sort of code in my app and it works...

Comment: I am adding subcontrols programmatically

Comment: Jay Gajjar your answer worked. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

make 'viewFilter' super view for that all sub controllers , means add that all sub controllers to viewFilter